# New-TimeSpan of two midnight dates skips every other day

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to simply calculate the number of days until a user's password expires. I use a TimeSpan to do this. My code in practice is as follows:

```
(New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0) -End (Get-Date $_.PasswordLastSet -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddDays(90)).Days
```

So if the current date is 90 days after the date when the password was last set, the days until password expiration would be 0.

Unfortunately, this code will return the same result for many consecutive days. For some reason I can't seem to get completely consistent results here, I assume it depends on the time of day, but am not sure why. Most of the time, we skip every other day. So if we ran this every day of the week, we would return 4,4,2,2,0,0.

To easily replicate, you can use the following:

```
$x = (get-date).AddDays(-90)
(New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date $x -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddDays(90) -End (get-date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)).Days
(New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date $x -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddDays(89) -End (get-date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)).Days
```

Comment: For me it returns `0` with `AddDays(90)` and `1` with `AddDays(89)`. This is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Just to confirm it can be reproduced. I tried this code on three different systems. On first one of them I got 0,1 continuously (as expected). But on two other systems I got 0,0. On repeated tests numbers were random 0,0 or 0,1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it. It depends on milliseconds. Sometimes difference would be 1 day and a few milliseconds. Sometimes, those few milliseconds will go to the other side, so difference would be 23 h 59 min 59 sec 78 milliseconds (for example). This is displayed as 0 days!

To see it, just remove `.Hours` from your example and try to replicate it.

```
    New-TimeSpan -Start (get-date $x -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddDays(89) -End (get-date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0)

Days              : 0
Hours             : 23
Minutes           : 59
Seconds           : 59
Milliseconds      : 78
Ticks             : 863990781260
TotalDays         : 0.999989330162037
TotalHours        : 23.9997439238889
TotalMinutes      : 1439.98463543333
TotalSeconds      : 86399.078126
TotalMilliseconds : 86399078.126
```

To resolve it, simply add one second to your calculation and you will get correct number of days.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I figured it was caused by the exact ticks. Using code from Martins answer, I was returning 1 and 0.99 at random. This solution should work.

Comment: @MacroPower No need to add an extra second if you check my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately @MartinBrandl I do actually require using get-date twice due to my exact use-case in the first code block of my question. I'm sure that will help future peoples, though.

Answer (score 2):

Why so difficult? You could substract the current date from the the date 90 days before and retrieve the `TotalDays`:

```
(Get-Date) - (Get-Date).AddDays(-90) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalDays
```

Now you only have to check whether the result is `-le 90`.

---

Note: Since Igor figured out that the TotalMilliseconds could be the root of your problem, I would suggest to retrieve the date only **once**:

```
$date= Get-Date
$date - $date.AddDays(-90) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalDays
```

Then you don't have to deal with Hours, Minutes, Seonds, Miliseconds and Ticks.

Comment: Actually, I think this exposes the issue. Using (TimeSpan).Days returns int. For some reason, if I use `(Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0) - (Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddDays(-90).AddDays(89) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalDays` I am returned 0.9999999..., rather than 1. This explains the skip. Do you know why this value is returned?

Comment: Strange! No clue. But you can simple *cast* the return value to an `[int]`: `[int]((Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0) - (Get-Date -hour 0 -minute 0 -second 0).AddDays(-90).AddDays(89) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalDays)`

Comment: I think I found the solution for you using the hint from Igor, check my edited answer

Comment: In original code, Marco is using twice Get-Date as once he is checking for current date and second time for a date when password was last set.