# PowerShell dates not comparing correctly

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to reboot PC's on the last weekday of the month.  The script runs daily at 7:25ish PM and the goal is to check today's date and see if it's the last weekday of the month.  If it is, it reboots the PC.  If it isn't it logs that it isn't.

I was thinking maybe PowerShell is comparing by ticks and the ticks are off slightly between run time of the `Get-Weekday` function and the `Get-Date` function.

**Log excerpt:**

```
COMP1 - 09/26/2018 17:24:08 - Not last weekday of month 09/28/2018 17:24:08 > 09/26/2018 17:24:08 
COMP1 - 09/27/2018 17:24:09 - Not last weekday of month 09/28/2018 17:24:09 > 09/27/2018 17:24:09 
COMP1 - 09/28/2018 17:24:01 - Not last weekday of month 09/28/2018 17:24:01 > 09/28/2018 17:24:01 
COMP1 - 09/28/2018 17:24:01 - Not last weekday of month 09/28/2018 17:24:01 > 09/28/2018 17:24:01
```

**Code:**

```
#Gets last weekday of the month
function Get-Weekday {
    param(
        $Month = $(Get-Date -format 'MM'),
        $Year = $(Get-Date -format 'yyyy'),
        $Days = 1..5
        )
    $MaxDays = [System.DateTime]::DaysInMonth($Year, $Month)
    1..$MaxDays | ForEach-Object {
            Get-Date -day $_ -Month $Month -Year $Year |
              Where-Object { $Days -contains $_.DayOfWeek }  
    }
}

    #Last day of the month
    $lwom = (Get-Weekday -Month (Get-Date).Month) | Select-Object -Last 1
    #Returns:  09/28/2018 17:24:16

    # Get Today's date.
    $ModDate = Get-Date
    #Returns:  09/28/2018 17:24:16

    #If Last day of month = Today's Date    
    if ( $lwom -eq $ModDate ) { 


        #Creates the wscript shell for the popup -- box automatically closes after 10 seconds, script sleeps for 60
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
        $wshell.Popup("This computer will reboot in 60 seconds.  Click OK and save your work!",10,"Save Your Data",48+0)
        $xCmdString = {sleep 60}
        Invoke-Command $xCmdString

        #Next popup created to reboot in 5 seconds.  
        $wshell.Popup("Rebooting...",4,"Rebooting",48+0)
        $xCmdString = {sleep 5}
        Invoke-Command $xCmdString
        Restart-Computer -Force
          }

    else { 
        Add-Content 'EOM-reboot_log.txt' "$env:computername - $ModDate - Not last weekday of month $lwom > $ModDate " 
         }
```

**Final Solution:**

```
function LastDayThisMonth {
    return (Get-Date -Day 1).Date.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
}

function WorkingDay {
    param ([datetime]$date=(Get-Date).Date)
    While (!([int]$date.DayOfWeek % 6)){$date=$date.AddDays(-1)}
    Return $date.Date
}

    $lwom = WorkingDay -Date (LastDayThisMonth) #Does not need .Date because it's already in the function.
    $ModDate = (Get-Date).Date  # .Date on the variables will return the date and ignores the time.  Time become 12:00:00 AM of both da


    if ( $lwom -eq $ModDate ) { 

                #Writes to the log file.
                Add-Content 'c:\EOM-reboot_log.txt' "$env:computername - $ModDate -  End of Month Weekday" 

                #Creates the wscript shell for the popup -- box automatically closes after 10 seconds, script sleeps for 60
                $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
                $wshell.Popup("This computer will reboot in 60 seconds.  Click OK and save your work!",10,"Save Your Data",48+0)
                $xCmdString = {sleep 60}
                Invoke-Command $xCmdString

                #Next popup created to reboot in 5 seconds.  
                $wshell.Popup("Rebooting...",4,"Rebooting",48+0)
                $xCmdString = {sleep 5}
                Invoke-Command $xCmdString
                Restart-Computer -Force
          }

    else { 
        Add-Content 'c:\EOM-reboot_log.txt' "$env:computername - $ModDate - Not last weekday of month $lwom > $ModDate " 
 }
```

Comment: You are guaranteeing that they will run at the exact same time? `$lwom -eq $ModDate`  is comparing dates and _times_. `$lwom.Date -eq $ModDate.Date` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028693/new-timespan-of-two-midnight-dates-skips-every-other-day Related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was thinking maybe PowerShell is comparing by ticks and the ticks are off slightly between run time of the Get-Weekday function and the Get-Date function.

Yep, this is easy to test to...

```
$date1 = Get-Date
$date2 = Get-Date

$date1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff")
$date2.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:fff")

$date1 -eq $date2
```

Running this repeatedly will show a mix of success and failures and shows that the only way `datetime` are equal is if *every* date / time value are respectively the same.

```
01-10-2018 09:11:02:729
01-10-2018 09:11:02:730
False

01-10-2018 09:11:04:378
01-10-2018 09:11:04:378
True
```

---

That being said,

`$lwom -eq $ModDate` is comparing dates *and times*. `$lwom.Date -eq $ModDate.Date` would just look at the dates themselves. So, unless you run this just before midnight, that would get consistent and predictable results.

Comment: Thank you!  I incorporated the .Date piece along with LotPings answer.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the last day in current month is IMO easier this way:

```
function LastDayThisMonth {
    return (Get-Date -Day 1).Date.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
}
```

A function to get the last working day for a given date/today:

```
function WorkingDay {
    param ([datetime]$date=(Get-Date).Date)
    While (!([int]$date.DayOfWeek % 6)){$date=$date.AddDays(-1)}
    Return $date.Date
}
```

- here `(!([int]$date.DayOfWeek % 6))` evaluates to true on sat/sun, so one day is subtracted

---

So on 9/30/2018 this:

```
$lwom = WorkingDay -Date (LastDayThisMonth)
```

returns

09/28/2018 00:00:00

avoiding the milliseconds/ticks problem.

**EDIT Just for completeness, an enhanced function WorkingDay with an `-After` switch to get the next WorkingDay (on) or after given date/today.**

```
function WorkingDay {
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0)] [datetime]$Date=(Get-Date).Date,
           [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)] [switch]$After)
    If($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("After")){[int]$Offset=1}else{[int]$Offset=-1}
    While (!([int]$Date.DayOfWeek % 6)){$Date=$Date.AddDays($Offset)}
    Return $Date.Date
}

"Date       WDayBefore WDayAfter"
"----       ---------- ---------"
-7..7|%{
    $Date=(get-Date).Date.AddDays($_)
    "{0,-10:ddd dd} {1,-10:ddd dd} {2,-10:ddd dd} " -f `
        $Date,
        (WorkingDay -Date $Date),
        (WorkingDay -Date $Date -After )
}
```

Output of the test routine (German locale):

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\01\SO_17-56.ps1
Date       WDayBefore WDayAfter
----       ---------- ---------
Mo 24      Mo 24      Mo 24
Di 25      Di 25      Di 25
Mi 26      Mi 26      Mi 26
Do 27      Do 27      Do 27
Fr 28      Fr 28      Fr 28
Sa 29      Fr 28      Mo 01
So 30      Fr 28      Mo 01
Mo 01      Mo 01      Mo 01
Di 02      Di 02      Di 02
Mi 03      Mi 03      Mi 03
Do 04      Do 04      Do 04
Fr 05      Fr 05      Fr 05
Sa 06      Fr 05      Mo 08
So 07      Fr 05      Mo 08
Mo 08      Mo 08      Mo 08
```